# Looping menu items by dragging and scrolling

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js, swiper.js

I'm trying to make a navigation menu. I want to change active menu item by dragging, scrolling and clicking. I'm using swiper library and it's very useful but I have a problem. There is no trouble with clicking or scrolling but when I drag and release the menu, looping stops at last item. I want it to keep looping until it slows down and stops. [Here is my JS-fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/kfnepx9j/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menu = new Swiper("#menu", {
    direction: "vertical",
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    slidesPerView: 7,
    mousewheel: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    freeMode: true,
    freeModeSticky: true,
    freeModeMomentumRatio: 0.8,
    freeModeVelocityRatio: 0.8,
    freeModeMinimumVelocity: 0.2,
    grabCursor: true
  });

});
```

I found [this similar issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2578) on swiper's github page but the owner says:

> This is by Swiper architecture design as it doesn't do any loop or
>   anything else during transition.

So I need to find an external solution. And also I don't have to use swiper despite I like it. I tried to use a couple of carousel libraries but I couldn't manage to fix my problem. Any suggestion is welcome.